# Using a client to POST data and accepting that Data through WCF POST method

Tags: c#, json, server, client

I am trying to send a base64String of data using my client to my server which uses WCF. I am having trouble with the Post method on both sides. I can't seem to receive anything or handle any of the data being sent over.

CLIENT SIDE:

```
  private void On_FingerDetect(object sender, FingerPrintArgs e)
    {
        if (!button1.Enabled)
        {
            byte[] newPrint = e.getPrint();
            string print = Convert.ToBase64String(newPrint);
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("print", print));

            // Post URL here
            PostAsync("http://localhost:4686/Service1.svc/doPost/", json);

            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Processing Finger Print";
            //toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = print;
        }
    }
    public async Task PostAsync(string uri, string data)
    {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, new StringContent(data));

        var content = response.Content;

        await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        button1.Enabled = true;
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = data;
    }
```

SERVER SIDE:

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "doPost/{value}")]
    [OperationContract]
    string doPost(string value);


public class Service1 : IService1
{

    static string myConnection = "DSN=MS Access Database";
    OdbcConnection myConn = new OdbcConnection(myConnection);
    OdbcCommand mycommand;
    OdbcTransaction transaction;
    OdbcDataAdapter adapter;

    public string doPost(string value)
    {
        // Trace.WriteLine("hello", value);
        byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
        OdbcConnection myConn = new OdbcConnection(myConnection);
        string query = "INSERT INTO fingerPrintDb (fingerPrint) VALUES ('" + value + "')";
        OdbcCommand mycommand = new OdbcCommand(query, myConn);

        myConn.Open();
        transaction = myConn.BeginTransaction();

        mycommand.Connection = myConn;
        mycommand.Transaction = transaction;
        mycommand.CommandText = query;

        mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        transaction.Commit();
        myConn.Close();

        return "Success";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's in your UriTemplate, you should not use the {} parm there. You're sending it via the POST's body.
I can't test it but this is my first guess.

Comment: I have taken the parameters out. When i run it i get this error:

Says im using :"GET /Service1.svc/doPost", when im suppose to be using post

Comment: Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Request","time":"2017-02-17T19:16:24.7684792Z","tags":{"ai.operation.name":"GET /Service1.svc/doPost","ai.operation.id":"JlJUJw/8Sdw=","ai.location.ip":"::1","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"DESKTOP-0U0ICHR","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"web:2.2.0-738"},"data":{"baseType":"RequestData","baseData":{"ver":2,"id":"JlJUJw/8Sdw=","name":"GET /Service1.svc/doPost","duration":"00:00:00.0050000","success":false,"responseCode":"405","url":"http://localhost:4686/Service1.svc/doPost","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true"}}}}

Comment: This is only when I run the server not with client